# Зачем нужен Docker, если есть Java virtual machine?

Tags: docker, jvm

Зачем нужен docker, если есть java virtual machine?
Разве она не транслирует байт код сразу в процессор, не зависимо от того на какой операционной системе выполняется?

Comment: `docker` != `JVM`

Comment: разве все и вся кодят на java?) странный вопрос как по мне.. Зачем компьютер если можно на рыбалку сходить

Comment: @Jour это вопрос джуна, большим сеньорам, прошу отнестись с пониманием)

Comment: @anton так они оба воспроизводят ваше приложение на любой из систем разве нет?

Comment: Докер не воспроизводит приложение на любой системе. Вы ошиблись. Вообще в докер можно запихнуть ПО, которое будет совсем не совместимо с приложением.

Comment: @Venoman9867 и как JVM воспроизведёт моё приложение на C++? Вообще вопрос из серии зачем нужен велосипед если есть мясорубка.

Comment: На Jvm можно запустить **только** код на Яве. А докер это такой примерно маленький компьютер, на котором можно запустить много чего всякого разного.

Comment: @Эникейщик Большое спасибо! Очень хорошее пояснение)